# Why can't I boot any Linux ISOs using Virtualbox (Windows) Version 6.0.10 r132072 (Qt5.6.2)?

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a new install of VirtualBox Version 6.0.10 r132072 (Qt5.6.2) on my HP Zbook running Windows 10.0.17763, which is also newly installed. After adding an IDE optical drive, I've tried attaching 3 different ISOs: 1) GParted, 2) RHEL 7.6 and 3) RHEL 5.3. In all three cases, the textual boot menu comes up, I make my selection, and from there it's nothing but black screen.

From the research I've done, this is usually caused by either 1) Hyper-V being enabled or b) insufficient video memory. I confirmed Hyper-V was already disabled and then maxed out the latter to 128mb. No change in behavior. I've attached my VBox log in hopes that someone can tell me what's up. From what I can tell, the relevant portion starts after:

00:00:02.996290 AIOMgr:     C:\Users\1128636\VirtualBox VMs\DPM\DPM.vmdk
00:00:02.996561 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'

But I can not see where it's going wrong. Thank you in advance!

Log:
https://pastebin.com/U2C4ffXA

Edit: Upon further examination, I see 2 potential oddities in the log:

531.00:00:02.151607 HM: HMR3Init: Attempting fall back to NEM: VT-x is not available

532.00:00:02.176611 NEM: WHvCapabilityCodeHypervisorPresent is TRUE, so this might work...

582.00:00:02.176888 NEM: Warning! Unknown CPU features: 0x178ffe7f7859f
584.00:00:02.177169 NEM: Warning! Unknown capability 0x1003 returning: 3f 38 00 00 00 00 00 00

Also, here is a list of my enabled features, which I dug up after seeing hat VT-x was for some reason not available. They look OK to me.

[Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9WDM.jpg)

Comment: Have you enabled hardware virtualization in the BIOS?

Comment: [Solution] Derived from the sole comment: Have you enabled hardware virtualization in the BIOS? – essjae

The answer was a resounding no, and this did fix the issue, TY!